# R package - How to specify a dependency version that is only available on github (AKA dev version)

Tags: r, github, package, dependencies

I'm need to fix the Description file for an R package and I need to specify a specific version of imported package (i.e. Brobdingnag  (>= 1.2-8) ).

But that version is not on Cran already (Cran has only up to 1.2-7) but is on github.

so I tried :

```
Imports:
     Brobdingnag  (>= 1.2-8)
Remotes:
    RobinHankin/Brobdingnag
```

But I predictably get:

```
checking package dependencies ... ERROR
  Package required and available but unsuitable version: ‘Brobdingnag’
```

And if I just use:

```
devtools::install_github("RobinHankin/Brobdingnag")
```

I get the 1.2-8 version without needing to specify it.

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks, David

Comment: You want to specify the recent version from github of this package, right?

Comment: Use `Remotes` in your package `DESCRIPTION`, as described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think specifying this would solve your problem

```
Imports:
     Brobdingnag  (>= 1.2.8)
Remotes:
    RobinHankin/Brobdingnag@HEAD
```